# Google bar graph from phpmyadmin data

Tags: html, graph, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a user statistic program which counts every online user on my page and I want a statistics in bar form to see/count the number of users every week/month. I tried using google charts and I still don't know how to thoroughly use it but I have seen an example which I tried.

But the problem is I have multiple uvon, (column name of ip addresses that opens the page), dt (column name for the time) and date_current (column name for the date the user opened the page). I can't seem to filter it all out in a single date and count how many users opened it for that day. It only shows the date. Please help

```html
<?php
include("database_config.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT uvon, dt, current_date FROM counter_summary";
$exec = mysqli_query($conn ,$query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);

       function drawMaterial() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['DATE', 'USERS'],
        <?php 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
           echo "['".$row[2]."', ".$row[1]."],"; 
          }
        ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'User Statistics',
          bars: 'vertical'
        };

        var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));
          material.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="barchart" style="width: 100%; height: 40em;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the resulting graph:
[image]

This is the sample data from the database:

[image]

Comment: are you trying to count each ip address per day only once? or a count of all the hits, regardless of ip address?

Comment: @WhiteHat Im trying to count all of the hits regardingless of ip addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following sql will give you the number of times an ip address connected per day...

```
SELECT current_date, count(*) FROM counter_summary group by current_date
```

note: I'm not sure if it is `current_date` as in your code,
or `date_current` as in the image of your table...

using the above, the rest of the code should work.